# Why wouldn't I make every eligable Kotlin class a data class?

Tags: kotlin, language-design

I'm of course excluding any reasons that involve violating the rules for what can be a data class. So if you know you won't need to inherit from it for example (although it's my understanding that rule is going away in Kotlin 1.1).

1. Are there any disadvantages to making a class a data class?
2. Why don't all eligible classes provide the functionality of a data class as long as they remain eligible? This should all be detectable by the compiler without needing a special keyword. Of course the answer to this might be obvious depending on the answer to question 1.
3. Is there any reason for me not to mark all of my eligible classes as data classes?

Comment: The rules of inheritance for data classes in 1.1 will be changed in another way: you still won't be able to inherit from data classes, but your data classes will be able to inherit from other (non-data) classes.

Comment: I think you will always have 3 sets of class types, and need all three.  Data work well for things that are immutable, need to compare all fields for equality and/or need copy constructor.  Sealed for things where you need finite class hierarchy.  And normal classes for all else.  Data classes do add weight which affects Android maybe more than say server development.

Comment: answers are going to be "it depends..." which means maybe the question is too broad.

Answer (score 10):

`data` modifier makes Kotlin generate common methods like `toString`, `hashCode`, `equals` for the most commons (%80) scenarios based on the primary constructor.

This shows 3 reasons why only few classes should be `data`:

1. Most non-data classes have a mix of properties defined in the primary constructor and in the body of the class. Also the primary constructor often has parameter that are not fields (but help initialise more complex fields in the body). In other words, `data` has very restrictive requirements which are rarely met by regular classes.
2. In addition to point 1, making a class `data` may hurt its extensibility. Even if the layout of the class in question conforms to the rules of `data` classes, later someone may want to add another property in the body of the class. In that case he will have to manually override `hashCode` because it may be used somewhere.
3. Marking a class `data` sends a message to the one who reads the code that you intend to use this class as a data career. Marking other classes will be misleading.

Comment: Additionally, the generated `copy` and and `componentX` methods increase code size and method count.

Comment: So would you say a class shouldn't be made data unless you're sure it will use at least one of the methods generated by a data class even if it is solely intended to be a carrier of data and has no class body? It can easily be made a data class later after all. Or should you use the data modifier anyway to make the code more readable and communicate your intention for the class?

Comment: Usually that depends on the intended behaviour of `equals`, whether I want to compare references or the data inside.

Answer (score -3):

Because of one the fundamental principle of OO programming: Encapsulation.
By design we deliberately limit ways in which other code can interact with external modules. This gives us maintainability (more powerful refactoring) and readability.